# Save Excel Data in Database in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

I have some excel files which i need to upload and save all the content in database.

**In my excel files sometimes some column which is not mandatory is not present but in cases where it is mandatory it will be present**

So How can i handle this situation single spring boot controller which run in all these 3 excel files?

For Example -

```
    Excel File 1

    Column1 | Column2 | Column3
    data1      data 2    data 3
    
    Excel File 2
    
    Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4
    data1      data 2    data 3   data 4
    
    Excel File 3
    
    Column1 | Column2 | Column4 
    data1      data 2    data 2
```

My Implementation

```
 for (int j = 0; j <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); j++) {
     Row currentRow = sheet.getRow(j);
     if (currentRow != null && currentRow.getCell(0)!=null) {
        Student student = new Student();
        // Common Fields which is in all the excel files
        student.setId((int)Math.round(currentRow.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue()));
        student.setName(currentRow.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
        
        // Rest of the fields (May be present in one excel but not present in other excel 
         vice-versa                                           
     }
 }
```

Comment: Do those columns have unique headers? If yes, use those to select the required columns…

Comment: yes all the headers are unique @deHaar

Comment: Make a check for the header row (the very first one, I guess). Determine which columns to be considered and store their indexes/numbers. Then iterate the remaining rows and use the stored numbers in order to create the `Student`s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fix worked for me.

```
for (int z = 0; z < row.getLastCellNum() - 1; z++) {
        String columnName = sheet.getRow(2).getCell(z).getStringCellValue(); // 2 is  heading row
        switch (columnName) {
           case "Column 1":
                 student.set(currentRow.getCell(z).getStringCellValue())
           break;
           case "Column 2":
                 student.set(currentRow.getCell(z).getStringCellValue())
           break;
           default:
           break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).